# Laravel sending Collection from Blade to VueJs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

i am new to Vue and i am trying to pass a collection from blade to Vue. Been stuck on this for a while now. I usually do this with axios get, but i wanted to try a new method. I would appreciate if someone could help me. I have attached the Vue, Blade, Controller and error images
[image: Controller]
[image: Vue]

[image: Blade]

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0):

You should unescape the json value from $employees.

`{!! $employees !!}`